# ggplot stacked bar chart: how can I display percentages on geom_text(aes(label = x) without making bars disappear?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

With the help of some stars on Stackoverflow, I've got a plot working like a charm. Here's the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
require(scales)
library(ggrepel)

# ingest some sample data
structure(list(Q52_bin = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("low", "medium", 
"high"), class = "factor"), Q53_bin = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("low", 
"medium", "high"), class = "factor"), Q57_bin = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("low", 
"medium", "high"), class = "factor"), Q4 = c(2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 
4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

names(df) <- c("Q52_bin", "Q53_bin", "Q57_bin", "response")
facet_names <- c(`Q52_bin` = "Spirituality", `Q53_bin` = "Politics L/R", `Q57_bin` = "Religiosity", `low`="low", `medium`="medium", `high`="high")
facet_labeller <- function(variable,value){return(facet_names[value])}
q4_levels = c("Not at all", "A little", "Some", "A lot", "A great deal")
df$response <- factor(df$response, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("5", "4", "3", "2", "1"))
df$response <- fct_recode(df$response, "Not at all" = "1", "A little" = "2", "Some" = "3", "A lot" = "4", "A great deal" = "5")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!response, names_to = "bin_name", values_to = "b") %>% 
  count(response, bin_name, b) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = "", fill = response)) +
  geom_col(position="fill", aes(fill=response)) +
  ### Problem line is below
  # geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=2) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrBr") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_grid(vars(b), vars(bin_name), labeller=as_labeller(facet_names)) + 
  labs(caption = "How much have you thought about climate change before today?", x = "", y = "") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL))
```

There are two problems here: first, I've not been able to find a good way to display percentages on the bars without using dplyr() to add new columns to the dataframe and this seems overly complicated (especially in light of the faceting I'm doing here). The second problem, is that the display of text makes the bars on the chart vanish!

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: include all the packages  required to run the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `position_fill` for the bars, so you need to use this for the text too:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!response, names_to = "bin_name", values_to = "b") %>% 
  count(response, bin_name, b) %>%
  group_by(bin_name, b) %>%
  summarize(label = scales::percent(n / sum(n)), response, n) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = "", fill = response)) +
  geom_col(position="fill", aes(fill=response)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrBr") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_grid(vars(b), vars(bin_name), labeller=as_labeller(facet_names)) + 
  labs(caption = "How much have you thought about climate change before today?", 
       x = "", y = "") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL))
```

[image]

Nice plot, by the way!

Comment: thanks! I'm feeling pretty pleased about how it is turning out. Any ideas on changing those labels to percentages within geom_text?

Comment: @JeremyKidwell sure -see my update. Create the labels by grouping by bin name and b, summarizing to get proportion and converting to percentages with scales::percent

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted the way I manipulate `df` from the previous question

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!response, names_to = "bin_name", values_to = "b") %>% 
  count(response, bin_name, b) %>% 
  group_by(bin_name,b) %>%
  mutate(perc=paste0(round(n*100/sum(n),1),"%")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = "", fill = response)) +
  geom_col(position=position_fill(), aes(fill=response)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = perc), position = position_fill(vjust=.5), size=2) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrBr") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  facet_grid(vars(b), vars(bin_name), labeller=as_labeller(facet_names)) + 
  labs(caption = "How much have you thought about climate change before today?", x = "", y = "") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL))
```

[image: likert]